# Error: React JS @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.0.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a ReactJs web app with firebase, I want to fetch the entries from the collection and display it in my webapp, but I am facing the issue.

Getting this error

[image]

**I am trying to access the firebase db using following code :**

```
db.collection("posts").onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data())) );
```

I also tried disabling firewall/antivirus but still facing the same issue.
I've a perfectly fine working internet connection and I'm sure internet is not the issue. Can somebody please suggest me a workaround solution for the same?

Comment: To be able to search, please post the redacted error message in text.

Comment: It cannot find the project. So this may be a configuration issue. If you are following a tutorial or documentation, please provide it to verify the steps.